# How to Compare Frozenset with list of tuple in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have a frozenset `A` and list `B`:

```
>>> a=frozenset(['A','B'])
>>> b=[('A','B'),('C',)]
>>> a in b
False #  my output expectation is True

>>> a=frozenset(['A','B'])
>>> b=[('A',),('B',)]
>>> a in b
False # as my output expectation
```

I want to compare and indicate that value of frozenset `a` in b is True. What sholud I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sets are unordered, you need to have a way to ensure correct ordering. In your case this'll work:

```
tuple(sorted(frozenset(['A','B']))) in [('A','B'),('C')]
```

Although you may want to create custom key function for more complex cases.